# Fasterxml Jackson ObjectMapper produces JSON string with '=' character

Tags: java, json, jackson

This question refers to Java library `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8` (`jackson-databind-2.8.8.jar`)

Given `object` is a POJO with:

```
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRawValue
private Map<String, String> innerDetail = new HashMap<String, String>();

innerDetail.put("Auth", "{\"node\":\"VALUE\"}");
```

(The POJO is also annotated with `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude`)

Then calling:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(object)
```

Returns a `String` containing:

```
"innerDetail":{Auth={"node":"VALUE"}
```

Surely the `=` (equals) should be a `:` (colon)?

I don't see that `=` is any part of JSON syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to your use of `@JsonRawValue`. The [JavaDoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/) for it says

> ...Warning: the resulting JSON stream may be invalid depending on your input value.

Comment: Well, OK. And using `@JsonInclude` gives instead a value of `"innerDetail":{Auth:{\"node\":\"VALUE\"}`. I need `@JsonRawValue' for the value but not the key it seems ....